# how to differ between two responses for observers in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, adapter, observers

I have a fragment where I Observe for 2 responses from server
One is for categories and the second is for products with category id=1.
the response for categories works fine
when the class receives the response for products...the list of products is added to list of categories and the adapter show them all.
How can I stop that??

```
viewModel.getCategories().observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner
    ) {
        if (it.error != "") {

            Toast.makeText(context, it.error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else if (it.success != "") {
            var categoriesList = it.success as ArrayList<Any>
            categories = viewModel.getCategoriesList(categoriesList)
            addCategories()

        }
    }

    viewModel.getProducts(1).observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner
    ) {
        if (it.error != "") {

            Toast.makeText(context, it.error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else if (it.success != "") {
            var productsList = it.success as ArrayList<Any>
            products = viewModel.getProductsList(productsList)
            addProducts()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Either `viewModel.getProductsList()` is returning *the categories + the products*, or `addProducts()` is just adding to the adapter's data without clearing what was already in there

Comment: Unfortunately it's neither